# podrias explicarme este query SQL?

Tags: jquery, sql, sqlite3

Algunos de ustedes seria tan amable de explicarme como esta funcionando esta consulta SQL, la entiendo en parte pero no en su totalidad. aclaro que solo afecta a dos tablas. Gracias

```
UPDATE PRODUCTO SET Cantidad = T2.stock
        FROM PRODUCTO T1
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT T3.id, T3.Cantidad - T4.Cantidad Stock
            FROM PRODUCTO T3
            INNER JOIN compra T4 ON T3.id = T4.id
        ) T2 ON T1.id = T2.id WHERE t2.id = 2
```

lo que entiendo es: UPDATE a la tabla PRODUCTO SET columna CANTIDAD = ???
desde la tabla PRODUCTO t1, entiendo es una referencia a PRODUCTO??
INNER JOIN quien es T3? que entiendo es tabla3.id, se refiere a T3 - T4 ????
FROM producto y ahora la refiere como T3??
INNER JOIN columna COMPRA t4?? se puede referir columnas tambien??

asi que mejor me la explican si. :)

Comment: Es por estas cosas que los alias de las tablas deben ser _descriptivos_...

Comment: Esta consulta es compleja, porque no tiene mucho sentido.. es mas, esta muy pobremente optimizada.. las explicaciones que te dieron, dejan ver que usar el filtro t2.id = 2 esta incorrectamente afuera, porque estas calculando la tabla t2 completa, para luego filtrarla. Seguro, esta consulta se puede hacer mucho mejor sin la subconsulta...

Comment: Igual muchas veces es mas facil explicar esto, si sabemos cual es la idea.. sobre todo, cuando el query esta pobremente escrito.

Comment: La consulta está mal porque está descontando el stock del producto (que debería de estar en otra tabla) con una compra aleatoria en vez de una compra específica. Otro detalle ilógico es que el stock no disminuye con las compras sino con las ventas.

Comment: aparte de eso, sabes x que una sola columna de la tabla compra actualiza todas las columnas de la tabla PRODUCTOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intento responderte

Lo que tienes es una consulta de actualización que tiene una consulta anidada.

A tu pregunta  T3 es un alias, cuando detrás de una tabla le pones otro nombre como por ejemplo `SELECT * FROM mitabla tabla1;` a partir de ahí podríamos decir que la tabla `mitabla` ya no se llama `mitabla` para ese select sino que `tabla1`. Para hacer una consulta debería ser `SELECT tabla1.campo FROM mitabla tabla1;`

Mi interpretación de la consulta:

Actualiza la tabla producto pon tanta cantidad como T2.stock.

T2.stock lo sacará del resultado de la consulta anidada.

La consulta anidada dice selecciona T3.id (donde T3 es producto), t3.cantidad-t4.cantidad (donde t4 es la tabla de compras) al resultado de esta operación la llamas stock (otro alias).

Y para saber que campos has de unir tienes que tener en cuenta el siguiente filtro: T1 unido con T2 cuando T1.id (producto.id) = t2.id (el resultado de la query.id)

Finalmente el t2.id (que podríamos traducirlo como producto.id de la subconsulta) debe ser = a 2.

Lo que tienes que buscar es información sobre el concepto de alias y de consulta anidada.

Espero haberte respondido

Un saludo!

Answer (score 1):

Yo creo que es más sencillo si la intentas interpretar desde dentro hacia afuera (por partes).
Así primero cogemos esto:

```
SELECT T3.id, T3.Cantidad - T4.Cantidad Stock
FROM PRODUCTO T3 INNER JOIN compra T4 ON T3.id = T4.id
```

Esto es una consulta que te devuelve una tabla con 2 campos `ID` y `STOCK` con sendos valores y 1..N registros.

Esto lo ponemos entre paréntesis y le aplicamos un alias `T2`, así que a partir de ahora cuando hable de `T2`, piensa en esa tabla.

| ID | Stock |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 3 | 300 |
| ... | ... |

Si coges la consulta exterior y pones `T2`, sería algo así:

```
UPDATE PRODUCTO SET Cantidad = T2.stock
FROM PRODUCTO T1 
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.id = T2.id 
WHERE t2.id = 2
```

Esta consulta actualiza la `CANTIDAD` de la tabla `T1` con lo que hay en el campo `STOCK` de la tabla `T2`, para el `ID=2`.

Lo único especial es que la tabla `T2`, en lugar de ser una tabla física de la Base de Datos, la ha montado **"al vuelo"**, por decirlo así, a partir de la select anterior (la de dentro del paréntesis).

Comment: saludos, me puedes decir porque actualiza TODAS las columnas de la tabla PRODUCTO en vez de su ID especificado de la tabla compra?

Comment: Revisa si has añadido correctamente el WHERE y en todo caso, si es necesario, puedes filtrar también la tabla "temporal" T2.

Comment: sip gracias ya he logrado modificarlo, con los consejos que me han dado aqui, espero que te pases x mi otra pregunta SQL para completarlo, porque ahora que puedo sumar las columnas descontando las cantidades de las ventas, cuando inserto cantidad de venta se descuenta el stock del almacen correcto? pero si me equiboco en la cantidad a despachar no puedo dar para atras a la resta de la existencia. en sqlite3